# Service created object is null when using @Autowired Spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data-jpa, jwt

When

> I am doing jwt login , I want to call findByUsernameAndPassword function in UserService, but when I use **@AutoWired** to create object in class CustomAuthenticationFilter it gets NullpointerException and it makes me unable to find User
> My code : UserRepository

```
import com.insmart.app.model.User;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
    @Query("SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.username = ?1")
   User findByUsername(String username);
    @Query("SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.username = ?1 AND u.password = ?2")
    User findByUsernameAndPassword(String username, String password);
}
```

My code : UserService

```
package com.insmart.app.service;

import com.insmart.app.model.User;
import com.insmart.app.repository.UserRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import java.util.List;
@Service
public class UserService{
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    public User save(User user) {
        user.setPassword(new BCryptPasswordEncoder().encode(user.getPassword()));
        return userRepository.save(user);
    }
    public User findById(Long id) {
        return userRepository.findById(id).get();
    }
    public void deleteById(Long id) {
        userRepository.deleteById(id);
    }
    public List<User> findAll() {
        return userRepository.findAll();
    }
    public User update(User user,Long id) {
        User user1 = userRepository.findById(id).get();
        user1.setDescription(user.getDescription());
        user1.setName(user.getName());
        user1.setEmail(user.getEmail());
        user1.setPassword(user.getPassword());
        return userRepository.save(user);
    }
    public User findByUsername(String username) {
        return userRepository.findByUsername(username);
    }
    public User findByUsernameAndPassword(String username,String password) {
        return userRepository.findByUsernameAndPassword(username,password);
    }
}
```

My code : CustomAuthenticationFilter

```
package com.insmart.app.filter;

import com.auth0.jwt.JWT;
import com.auth0.jwt.algorithms.Algorithm;
import com.insmart.app.model.Organization;
import com.insmart.app.model.User;
import com.insmart.app.service.UserService;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class CustomAuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {
    private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException {
       String username = request.getParameter("username");
       String password = request.getParameter("password");
        User user = new User();
        userService = new UserService();
        try {
            user = userService.findByUsernameAndPassword(username,password);
            log.info("\n username: {} \n password: {}",username,password);
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user.getUsername(),user.getPassword(),Collections.emptyList());
            log.info("attemptAuthentication {}",authenticationToken);
            return authenticationManager.authenticate(authenticationToken);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain, Authentication authResult) throws IOException, ServletException {
        User user =(User) authResult.getPrincipal();
        Algorithm algorithm = Algorithm.HMAC256("secret".getBytes());
        String accessToken = JWT.create().
                withSubject(user.getUsername()).
                withExpiresAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()+10*60*1000)).
                withIssuer(request.getRequestURL().toString()).
                withClaim("roles",user.getOrganizations().stream().map(Organization::getOrganization).collect(Collectors.toList())).
                sign(algorithm);
        String refreshToken = JWT.create().
                withSubject(user.getUsername()).
                withExpiresAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()+30*60*1000)).
                withIssuer(request.getRequestURL().toString()).
                sign(algorithm);
        response.setHeader("access-token",accessToken);
        response.setHeader("refresh-token",refreshToken);

    }
}
```

My code : SecurityConfig

```
package com.insmart.app.config;

import com.insmart.app.filter.CustomAuthenticationFilter;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;

@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("admin")
                .password(passwordEncoder().encode("admin"))
                .roles("ADMIN")
                .authorities("ACCESS_TEST1","ACCESS_TEST2")
                .and()
                .withUser("user")
                .password(passwordEncoder().encode("user"))
                .roles("USER")
                .authorities("ACCESS_TEST1");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable();
        http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        // http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll();
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/css/**", "/index").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/user/**").authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin().loginPage("/login")
                .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/logout");
        http.addFilter(new CustomAuthenticationFilter((authenticationManagerBean())));
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

I want to use findByUsernameAndPassword in CustomAuthenticationFilter class, So I used @Autowired in UserService, I tried adding @Service in CustomAuthenticationFilter class it doesn't work either. I hope you can help me. I appreciate your help

Comment: Try removing userService = new UserService(); this line from CustomAuthenticationFilter  class as its already autowired you don't need to initialize it again

Comment: I tried but the following error occurs:
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot call "com.insmart.app.service.UserService.findByUsernameAndPassword(String, String)" because "this.userService" is null

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't work